# Blazor Server-Side variable doesn't update after function call because of OnAfterRenderAsync

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have have a Server-Side Blazor app with a simple index.razor Page. My goal is to read sessionStorage  and use it's content. But for now I am trying to make baby steps to understand what is going on.

This is the html

```
@inject Blazored.SessionStorage.ISessionStorageService sessionStorage

<button @onclick="TestInc">TEST</button>
<h1>@tutu</h1>
```

I only have a text to show the the number and a simple button to increment my value
And this is the code

```
@code {
    private int tutu = 0;
    public string sNom;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            bool isConnected = await sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<bool>("isConnected");
            //if (!isConnected)
            //{
            //    NavManager.NavigateTo("/Login", forceLoad: true);
            //}
            sNom = sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("Nom").Result;
        }
    }
    private void TestInc()
    {
        tutu += 1;
    }
}
```

For some reason, the code works fine if I comment the whole `OnAfterRenderAsync` function. The page will show the counter and update it when it I click on the button. However if I have the function `OnAfterRenderAsync` uncommented and do it's thing, the counter is not updated at all and if I put a breakpoint inside `TestInc` it never reaches it.

I am relatively new to Blazor so I might be missing something really obvious here.

What I really would like to achieve is get sessionStorage variable (a username for example) and display it inside my HTML without having to click on a button or reloading the page

Comment: remember to call `base.OnAfterRenderAsync`

Comment: Where should I call it ? 
In the doc it is not mentionned https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#after-component-render-onafterrenderasync

Comment: No repro. Start again and make minimal changes, _only_ the code posted above and see if you can demonstrate your problem. See [mre].

Comment: Calling the base method is a best practice but I don't think it's the problem here.

Comment: Does the bool IsConnected change in de code? If not the problem is probally in the core of the application missing scripts for example.

Comment: not calling the base method is not the reason of your problem

Comment: Alright I also had a ` sNom = sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("Nom").Result;` inside my `OnAfterRenderAsync` which seems to be the main problem. Commneting that specific line makes the rest work

Comment: .Result isn't needed because you are expecting a string and not a object. And use await for your sessionStorage.GetItem.

Comment: `.Result' can and will deadlock, never use it.

Comment: I wanted to try it to make the method no Async. Turns ou it was a really bad idea and made a deadlock causing the strange behavior. Thanks a lot for your help guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple:

```
//sNom = sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("Nom").Result;
sNom = await sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("Nom");
```

1. never use `.Result` or `.Wait()`
2. always aim for an unbroken  'chain' of awaits
3. treat "lacks await" and "is not awaited" Warnings as if they were Errors.

Comment: Yes that was it, the .Result caused a deadlock and or this strange not responding behavior

Answer (score 1):

this will work if your sessionStorage has a item called Nom

```
sNom = await sessionStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("Nom");
```

Comment: That was it, I wanted to try the .Result to not use await and Async methods. Turns out that was a really bad idea